Const reference to structure with member reference to non-const
Is the next code valid?
#include <cassert>

struct MyRef {
    int &valueRef;
};

void modify(const MyRef &ref) {
    ref.valueRef = 42;
}

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    const MyRef ref{x};
    modify(ref);
    assert(x == 42);
    return 0;
}

It compiles and works without apparent errors.
My understanding is that const reference acts as if const qualifier was applied to all members of the struct MyRef. And const has no effect on valueRef's type because it's reference and all references are "const" in the sense that it can't be reassigned to point to a different object. However as I discovered int & const ref; is ill-formed declaration (dcl.ref/1), and so in turn accessing valueRef via const MyRef & should be invalid.

The member is not const, compare with https://godbolt.org/z/q6fKdn1jE. For const correctness you would need a const getter. Another lesson in not exposing member variables directly.

const is applied to *this, this->valueRef aka (*this).valueRef is still int&.

@PepijnKramer I'm not asking whether it's good or bad. I'm asking whether it's valid and if so why.

@3CxEZiVlQ (int & const) is ill-formed

Adding const to int& does not produce const int&, but stays int&. Try static_assert(std::same_as<std::add_const_t<int&>, int&>);.

"(int & const) is ill-formed" int &const valueRef makes no sense because valueRef is already const, you can't rebind valueRef to another variable.

@3CxEZiVlQ The question is not "Why (int & const) is ill-formed?"

You repeated that 3 times so the question looks like "Why (int & const) is ill-formed?". BTW I just commented above, not answered.

your arent declaring a int & const

dcl.ref/1 is irrelevant here. It only applies to declaring a variable of reference type and trying to apply const on reference (instead of any other element of the type). Reference can receive extra const specifier through other means (e.g. in templates or though class like in your example) and that does nothing to it, that's not what dcl.ref/1 is talking about. Your code is well-formed and defined C++, but I'd never let it through a code review.

@Yksisarvinen My concern was that exception for getting cv through template or typedef is specified explicitly in dcl.ref/1 but  for my case it's not specified (at least not explicitly).

dcl.ref/1 is specifically only talking about declarations. Declarations you write in your code. In your code there is no such declaration. You seem to assume that declaring const MyRef ref{x}; would indirectly/implicitly be a declaration of a int & const, but thats not correct, its a false premise, hence the quote is irrelevant.
